# Convert image taken from camera to bytearray, then pass to next activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I'm trying to take a picture with the camera, then have it converted to a bytearray and passed on to the next activity. I can't figure out how to do it though. This is the code from the activity that takes the picture:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TakePictureActivity extends Activity {

    public final static int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TakePicture();
    }

    public void TakePicture() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // I don't know what to do here
    }

}
```

I already have the next activity set up so it can receive the bytearray and decode it, so all I need help with is this.

Comment: Why do you have an `Activity` with no 'view'? The point of an `Activity` is that it is basically a UI framework - in other words, it's not just some sort of general class, it's meant to show a user interface. Simply put your `TakePicture()` and `onActivityResult(...)` method into the other `Activity` and you won't need to worry about passing the image.

Comment: @Squonk You know, I have no idea why I did that. I just moved it to the other activity and it works perfect! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
byte[] inputData=null;
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    InputStream iStream =   getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    inputData = getBytes(iStream);
}
```

getBytes method

```
public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
      ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      int bufferSize = 1024;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

      int len = 0;
      while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
      }
      return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Squonk pointed out, I should have just moved the camera intent and OnActivityResult into the next activity instead of its own. It works now.